# CI CD for service file in angular 6 app using azure DevOps with VSTS

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, angular6, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have my angular 6 application up and running in my production environment. But I have a small problem here. I have implemented a back end for my angular application using angular **service** & it looks like this **:**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CampaignService {

  constructor(private _http :HttpClient) { }

//   CampaignsInfo(){
//     return this._http.get('http://localhost:64674/api/GetCampaignsInfo');
//   }

//   MetricsInfo(){
  
//     return this._http.get('http://localhost:64674/api/LandingPageMetrics');
//   }
  
//  BeneficiaryGroupInfo(){
//    return this._http.get('http://localhost:64674/api/GetBeneficiaryGroupInfo');
//  }

//  BeneficiaryBatchInfo(Id){
//    return this._http.post('http://localhost:64674/api/GetBeneficiaryBatchInfo', Id);
//  }
 

//   QuestionnaireInfo(Id){
//     return this._http.post('http://localhost:64674/api/GetQuestionnaires', Id);
//   }
 
//   CampaignBeneficiaresInfo(Id){
//     return this._http.post('http://localhost:64674/api/GetCampaignBeneficiares' , Id);
//   }

//   CampaignTreemapDataInfo(Id){
//    return this._http.post('http://localhost:64674/api/GetTreemapData' , Id);
//  }


  //Prod Public


  CampaignsInfo(){
    return this._http.get('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/portal/api/GetCampaignsInfo');
  }

  MetricsInfo(){
  
    return this._http.get('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/portal/api/LandingPageMetrics');
  }

  
 BeneficiaryGroupInfo(){
   return this._http.get('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/portal/api/GetBeneficiaryGroupInfo');
 }

 BeneficiaryBatchInfo(Id){
   return this._http.post('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/portal/api/GetBeneficiaryBatchInfo', Id);
 }
 

  QuestionnaireInfo(Id){
    return this._http.post('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/portal/api/GetQuestionnaires', Id);
  }
 
  CampaignBeneficiaresInfo(Id){
    return this._http.post('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/portal/api/GetCampaignBeneficiares' , Id);
  }

  CampaignTreemapDataInfo(Id){
   return this._http.post('http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/portal/api/GetTreemapData' , Id);
 }


  
}
```

Everytime I have to comment the localhost after the development and un-comment my production URL's in my service and it's really frustrating. Is there a way to automate this process in VSTS (Git version)? Any help is much appreciated. I know i'm asking too much, But i'm beating my head around this for days now.

Comment: Do you want during the build to replace the localhost to the prod ip's?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes sir, I did managed to implement that using the environment.ts and environment.prod.ts files and replacing the parameters dynamically in my service.ts file. Thank you for asking.